# average gap between the dates mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table client which has a column "appointment"

```
------------------------------
Clentname | appointmentday   |
------------------------------
Jonna     | January 22, 2018 |
Jonna     | August 31, 2017  |
Jonna     | June 27, 2017    |
```

I want to find the average gap between the dates,

I found a solution here but isn't working.

```
$intervals = array();

foreach ($lifeSpanArray as $key) {
    $newTimeAdd = new DateTime($key["timeAdded"]);
    $newTimeRead = new DateTime($key["timeRead"]);
    $interval = $newTimeAdd->diff($newTimeRead);
    $intervals[] = $interval->days;//get days
}

if(!empty($intervals))
{
    $average = average($intervals);
}

function average($arr)
{
   return array_sum($arr)/count($arr);
}
```

Comment: This has something to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

A fish:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(client_id INT NOT NULL
,appointment_date DATE NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(client_id,appointment_date)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2018-01-22'),
(1,'2017-08-31'),
(1,'2017-06-27');

SELECT AVG(diff) 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.appointment_date) next
            , DATEDIFF(MIN(y.appointment_date),x.appointment_date) diff 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.client_id = x.client_id 
          AND y.appointment_date > x.appointment_date 
        GROUP 
           BY x.client_id
            , x.appointment_date) n;
+-----------+
| AVG(diff) |
+-----------+
|  104.5000 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Query shows so many errors like:An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 22)

Comment: @StellaRoss OK, but that's obviously nothing to do with the code provided above.